# divide by css calculated width instead of element width attribute with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have this code:

```
$('.blogimages img').css('marginLeft', function() { 
    return - $(this).width()/2;
});
```

However it's taking the `width="750"` attribute instead of the newly calculated with my stylesheet has given it.

Image setup example:

```
<div class="img-wrap" style="position: relative; ">
    <img class="insert-all wide" title="23" src="http://www.threefishfiesta.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/231.jpeg" alt="" width="750" height="500">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.client-small .img-wrap {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.img-wrap .wide{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.img-wrap .tall{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Is there a way to rewrite this to take the css generated width instead of the html attribute width?

Thanks!

Comment: could u paste some more code here html/css ?

Comment: try removing inline html width and height values

Comment: it's generated by wordpress.. any idea how to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use outerWidth() - http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Comment: You can edit the HTML in WordPress, just have to find what template it's in and go to Appearance > Editor. I have some experience working in WordPress - if you link me the site I might be able to tell you which template it is?

Comment: It's not part of the template. The images are generated by the media uploader.

Comment: Ok, in that case you need to go to file that specifies that stuff, I think it'll be wp-includes/media.php - there should be somewhere there that sets the HTML for the images. Try commenting out that bit and uploading, see if that works.

Comment: Is there no way to to remove them with jQuery?

Comment: what about - $(img).attr('width','')

Comment: actually, sorry, you can do this directly - removeAttr('width')

Comment: That definitely removed it, though now the jQuery ends with a margin-left value of 0..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16069/discussion-between-zenkaty-and-reuben)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the css value? $(this).css('width')/2;