# Add form checkboxes with the img's title before it into each div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How can I add a form checkbox to each of these divs with increasing id's?

Currently have:

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img title="1" src="img.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img title="2" src="img.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img title="3" src="img.jpg" />
</div>
```

and I want

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img title="1" src="img.jpg" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img title="2" src="img.jpg" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2" />
</div>
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img title="3" src="img.jpg" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="3" value="3" />
</div>
```

jQuery or Javascript would be awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: just to add up to previous answers and add a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/GdzLJ/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("img").each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("title");
    $(this).parent().append("<input type='checkbox' name='"+ id +"' value='"+ id +"' />");
});
```

Comment: Thanks!! You Rock! Think you could solve this one? ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206790/divide-by-css-calculated-width-instead-of-element-width-attribute-with-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should solve:

```
$('.img-wrap img').each(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('title');
  $('<input type="checkbox" name="'+id+'" value="'+id+'" />').insertAfter(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var ele, val;
    $("div.img-wrap img").each(function(){
        ele = $(this);
        val = ele.attr("title");
        ele.after($('<input type="checkbox" name="' + val + '" value="' + val + '" />'));
    });
});​
```